# jQuery to make adjacent divs the same height

Tags: jquery, containers

I have a series of fields like :

```
<div class="field-label-inline">
  <div class="field-label">something1</div>
  <div class="field-items">
     <div class="field-item">sometext1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field-label-inline">
  <div class="field-label">something2</div>
  <div class="field-items">
     <div class="field-item">sometext2</div> 
</div>
```

I want to make all the instances of the .field-label div the same height as the adjacent .field-items div (the height of this div varies according to its content). Sadly my jQuery is almost non-existent; here is my best but failed attempt :

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

  $('.field-label-inline > .field-label', this).each(function(){

    var itemsHeight = 0;

    itemsHeight = $(this + .field-items).height();

    $(this).height(itemsHeight);

  });
});
```

Comment: Why couldn't you just use CSS?

Comment: Use .height().http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 0):

give your .field-label-inline class a fixed height, say 500px, and then give .field-label and .field-items a height of 100%. i would do this in css, but the jquery is below.

```
$(".field-label-inline").css("height","500px");
$(".field-label").css("height","100%");
$(".field-items").css("height","100%");
```

Comment: The .field-items div varies in height depending on the content of the .field-item div so CSS can't provide a solution.  It must be dynamic.

The jQuery needs to find the height of each .field-items div and apply that to the .field-lable div.  Unfortunately this is what I can't work out the jQuery to do.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually.  This works.  I've no idea if it is a 'good' solution though.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

  $('.field-label-inline .field-label').each(function(){

  var itemsHeight = 0;

  itemsHeight = $(this).next().height();

  $(this).height(itemsHeight);

  });
});
```

Comment: It looks OK to me, though the indentation could do with repair. Also, you can merge two lines: `var itemsHeight = $(this).next().height()`.